# Select-List displays Keys instead of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

I have a stange phenomenon where I'm stuck at the moment as I don't know where the error comes from.

My code is like this:

```
<input id="selectClassInput" name="selectClass" list="selectClass" type="text" >
<datalist id="selectClass">
   <option value="DUMMY1">0</option>
   <option value="s">24</option>
   <option value="d">25</option>
</datalist>
```

My problem is with displaying the datalist. If I click on the arrow I'm getting only the numbers like here:
[image]

After selecting for example '25' I'm getting the value 'd'. That is correct BUT I don't want to display the numbers. Instead I want to display the value of this datalist in this drop-down field.

If I do something like this:

```
<input id="selectClassInput" name="selectClass" list="selectClass" type="text" >
<datalist id="selectClass">
    <option value="DUMMY1">DUMMY1</option>
    <option value="s">s</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
 </datalist>
```

I'd naturally get the correct display, but I would like to add the ID, so that I can bind the click event with the ID of the selection and not the label.

Comment: I don't understand why the second example doesn't work for you, as it meets the requirement you state.

Comment: I want to bind the datalist with IDs. After selection want to display data regarding this selection. But the List should be able to have the same lable multiple times. Only the ID should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of data attribute to find the id of option clicked from the list and keep value as labels,

see below code

```js
$(function(){
  $('#selectClassInput').on('change', function(e){
     var val = $(this).val();
     var id = $('#selectClass').find('option[value="' + val + '"]').data('id');
     console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="selectClassInput" name="selectClass" list="selectClass" type="text" >
<datalist id="selectClass">
   <option value="DUMMY1" data-id="0">DUMMY1</option>
   <option value="s"  data-id="24">s</option>
   <option value="d" data-id="25">d</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. How can I mark this answer as the right answer?

Comment: Put your mouse on zero on left side of the answer and move below down arrow where you will see right mark, click on it and it will turn to green which means you have accepted the answer and marked it correct. You can upvote the answer too by clicking up arrow.